# Chaining Extension methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, method-chaining

Is it possible to create an extension method that returns the instance that is invoking the extension method?

I would like to have an extension method for anything that inherits from `ICollection<T>`, returns the object.  Much like how jQuery always returns the jquery object.

```
public static object AddItem<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T itemToAdd)
{
    collection.Add(itemToAdd);
    return collection;
{
```

I imagine something like above, but I am not sure how to get back to the parent to the "this" object type for use of something like this:

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>().AddItem(5);
```

EDIT: Just wanted to be clear that i was hoping for a single generic constraint solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to return the specific type, you can use a generic constraint:

```
public static TCollection AddItem<TCollection, TElement>(
    this TCollection collection,
    TElement itemToAdd)
    where TCollection : ICollection<TElement>
{
    collection.Add(itemToAdd);
    return collection;
}
```

I tested this and it works in VS2010.

**Update (regarding jQuery):**

jQuery chaining works very well because JavaScript uses dynamic typing. C# 4.0 supports `dynamic`, so you can do this:

```
public static dynamic AddItem<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T itemToAdd)
{
    collection.Add(itemToAdd);
    return collection;
}
```

However, I do recommend the generic constraint version, since it is more type-safe, more efficient, and allows IntelliSense on the returned type. In more complex scenarios, generic constraints aren't always capable of expressing what you need; in those cases, `dynamic` can be used (though it won't bind to additional extension methods, so it doesn't work well with chaining).

Comment: Thanks.  I did this at first, but didnt like the 2 generics specification.  BUT, i figured out that since the type is implied with TCollection, you actually dont have to specify it in code.

Comment: Right. The code to use it is exactly what you had in your question; no explicit type parameters are necessary. I also updated the answer regarding jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't have VS open to try this, something along these lines should work:

```
public static TCollection AddItem<TCollection, TItem>(TCollection collection, 
                                                      TItem itemToAdd) 
where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>
{
    collection.Add(itemToAdd);
    return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have 2 conflicting goals, and it comes down to what do you want your extension method to return:

- The instance that invoked the extension method (the collection)
- OR the item that was added to the collection

From your example usage, quoted here:

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>().AddItem(5);
```

You make it look like you want to return the collection.  In any case, that assignment still won't work without a cast, since your extension method would need to have a return type of ICollection, like this:

```
public static ICollection<T> AddItem<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T itemToAdd)
{
    collection.Add(itemToAdd);
    return collection;
}
```

That would allow you to do this:

```
List<int> myList = (List<int>) new List<int>().AddItem(5);
```

Now if you'd rather return the object that was added, you still shouldn't have a return type of `object`.  You should take advantage of your generic type parameter, and return `T`, like this:

```
public static T AddItem<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T itemToAdd)
{
    collection.Add(itemToAdd);
    return itemToAdd;
}
```

However, if you're returning the item that was added, you won't be able to chain like this:

```
List<int> myList = (List<int>) new List<int>().AddItem(5);
```

, since the return type of `AddItem(5)` is *not* ICollection, but it's `T` (`int`, in this case).  You can still chain though, just off of the value added, like this:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.AddItem(5).DoSomethingWithMyInt(); // Not very useful in this case
```

It seems like the first scenario is more useful (returning the collection), because it does allow you chain, right off of the initial assignment statement.  Here's a larger example of that:

```
List<int> myList = (List<int>) new List<int>().AddItem(1).AddItem(2);
```

Or, if you don't want to cast, you can call `ToList()` on the ICollection that comes back:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>().AddItem(1).AddItem(2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: Just wanted to be clear that i was hoping for a single generic constraint solution.

In this case you're out of luck because return type conversions can be covariant, but not contravariant (i.e. you cannot implicitly convert from `ICollection<T>` to `List<T>`), so without a generic return type this cannot be done.

What's wrong with specifying 2 type parameters anyway? They can be inferred by the arguments you provide to the function so you won't even really notice them in your calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `ICollection<T>`instead of `object` and everything should work like you intended it.

Comment: No, because he's assigning it to a variable of type `List<T>`.

Comment: That is correct.  I mistakenly thought the cast wouldnt work, but that was ReSharper putting a red squigly line & just taking a long time to update after i replaced some previous syntax.